# User/Group Permissions in Active Directory

Tags: c#, permissions, active-directory

Where can I find an example that does the following?

1. Pulls a user from Active Directory.
2. Gets the groups the user is a member of.
3. Gets a list of permissions assigned to each group.

This seems like a simple task but I can't find a solution.

The overall goal is to assign custom permissions and use them to control rights within an application.

Comment: I'm using Active Directory APIs in .NET/C#.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find a user
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

if(user != null)
{
   // do something here....     
}

// find the group in question
GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "YourGroupNameHere");

// if found....
if (group != null)
{
   // iterate over members
   foreach (Principal p in group.GetMembers())
   {
      Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", p.StructuralObjectClass, p.DisplayName);
      // do whatever you need to do to those members
   }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

The last point: permissions. Those aren't stored in Active Directory - and therefore, you can't retrieve those from any AD code.

Permissions are stored on the individual file system items, e.g. files and/or directories - or other objects (like registry keys, etc.). When you have an AD group or user account, you can read it's SID (Security Identifier) property - that SID will show up in ACL's (Access Control Lists) all over Windows - but from the user or group, there's no mechanism to get all permissions it might have anywhere in the machine/server.

Permissions for files and directories can e.g. be retrieved using the `.GetAccessControl()` method on the `FileInfo` and `DirectoryInfo` classes:

```
FileInfo info = new FileInfo(@"D:\test.txt");
FileSecurity fs = info.GetAccessControl();

DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\test\");
DirectorySecurity ds = dir.GetAccessControl();
```

Deciphering and making sense of those is a whole different story altogether!

Comment: That was my suspicion.  Thank you for your help.