# Iterate through permissions on a file in the windows file system in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am developing an application in C#. The goal is to get the permissions on a given file in the file system.

This would include inherited permissions and permissions directly assigned to the file.

I want to get `AD groups`, `local groups` and `domain users` and `local users` who have been assigned `Read, Write, Read & Execute, List Folder Contents, Modify and Full Control` on a given file.

I am not sure how to get the above for a given file. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create a [`FileIOPermission`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermission%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object for each file and pick out the [`AllFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermission.allfiles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) member.  It can be any combination of `AllAccess`, `Append`, `NoAccess`, `PathDiscovery`, `Read`, and `Write`, though obviously only a few of those make logical sense.

You might also be interested in [the `GetPathList()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermission.getpathlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), obviously.

For the rest, there's also the [`System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  That'd be too big for me to dig into, here, but...ah, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6850981/3438854) is a really good start.